# Generate all \$3\times 3\$ magic squares

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity

Though challenges involving magic squares abound on this site, none I can find so far ask the golfer to print / output all normal magic squares of a certain size. To be clear, a normal magic square of order \$n\$ is:

1. An \$n\times n\$ array of numbers.
2. Each positive integer up to and including \$n^2\$ appears in exactly one position in the array, and
3. Each row, column, and both main- and anti-diagonals of the array sum to the same "magic number".

Your challenge is to write the shortest program that prints all normal magic squares of order 3. There are 8 such squares. For the purposes of this challenge, the characters surrounding the output array, such as braces or brackets that accompany arrays in many languages, are allowed. For a non-optimized example in python, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636633/how-to-prove-that-a-3-times-3-magic-square-must-have-5-in-its-middle-cell/4236803#4236803). Happy golfing!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861) This looks like a reasonably well-specified challenge, but for future reference, we strongly recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to the main site.

Comment: Also, your output requirement "print them, and the brackets are allowed" is unusual; I'd recommend using the [site default rules about I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447), to allow (for example) submissions to return the array from a function rather than submit a full program.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3156/66833) (generate a magic square of a given size, rather than generate all)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the wording.  Is there any input to the code at all?  The wording and title of most of the body seem to imply that we take \$n\$ and produce all the order \$n\$ magic squares, but the final bit just says order 3.

Comment: @MarcMush I've clarified that there are 8 such solutions for the 3x3 problem.

Comment: @WheatWizard there is no input to the code, it is for generating all 3x3 squares. i started with a challenge for the general case but simplified it to the 3x3 only. i'll edit the title, thanks!

Comment: Can we output the 8 matrices without separators, [like this](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38RKybgk0schQrEk4P9/AA)? (The output is unambiguous because each matrix is known to have 3 rows). If not, what separators are allowed?

Comment: And do we need to have separators for the rows of the magic squares, or can we output each as, say, a string of 9 digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“ÑṆ6Ẉ’Ds3ZU$Ƭ;U$
```

A niladic Link that yields a list of eight lists of lists of digits, the eight magic squares.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//4oCcw5HhuYY24bqI4oCZRHMzWlUkxqw7VST/w4dH4oKsauKBvgoK/w)**

#### How?

Builds one then constructs the other seven using rotations and reflections.

```
“ÑṆ6Ẉ’Ds3ZU$Ƭ;U$ - Link: no arguments
“ÑṆ6Ẉ’           - base 250 literal = 276951438
      D          - decimal digits -> [2,7,6,9,5,1,4,3,8]
       s3        - split into threes -> [[2,7,6],[9,5,1],[4,3,8]]
            Ƭ    - collect up until a fixed point is found under:
           $     -   last two links as a monad - f=rotate(current):
         Z       -     transpose - i.e. swap rows with columns
          U      -     upend - i.e. reverse each row
               $ - last two links as a monad - f=add_reflections(four_rotations):
              U  -   upend - i.e. revese each row of each rotation
             ;   -   (four_rotations) concatenate (upended)
```

---

##### Alternatives

```
⁽Xð×3Œ?s3ZU$Ƭ;U$
```

```
“=ẹʋ‘×3D‘ZU$Ƭ;U$
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

Outputs every magic square, each as three comma-separated rows in the form: `XXX,XXX,XXX`.

```python
for c in'\zÁßİĺ':print(f'{ord(c)*1780218+275171220:,}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFZITNPnZE7pupw4@H5RzYc2aVuVVCUmVeikaZenV@UopGsqWVobmFgZGihbWRuamhuaGRkYKVTq675/z8A)

#### Explanation

There are only eight magic squares, each of which are rotations/reflections of each other. In their flattened decimal representation, they are:

```python
276951438, 294753618, 438951276, 492357816, 618753294, 672159834, 816357492, 834159672
```

What's remarkable about these numbers is that they are all congruent to `1017648 (mod 1780218)`, meaning they can be expressed in the form `x*1780218+1017648`. In the code, we actually use `x*1780218+275171220` as the formula instead, since it takes up less bytes to represent in our string. The number is then comma-formatted with `f'{x:,}'` to show the separation of the rows.

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

The same method but does not contain unicode characters, is (annoyingly) the same length.

```python
n=50863752
for c in b'~	PFP	':n-=~c*1780218;print(f'{n:,}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/W1MDCzNjc1IgrLb9IIVkhM08hSb2OM0DWTTaAU90qT9e2LlnL0NzCwMjQwrqgKDOvRCNNvTrPSqdWXfP/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
4:"3tYL@X!tP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38RKybgk0schQrEk4P9/AA) Outputs all matrices without separation. Note that the output is unambiguous.

Alternatively, [this version](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38RKybgk0schQtEguTKg8v9/AA) uses a line as separator, for 15 bytes.

#### How it works

```
4:      % Range [1 2 3 4]
"       % For each k in that range
  3tYL  %   Magic square of size 3 (gives one of the 8 possible squares)
  @     %   Push k
  X!    %   Rotate matrix 90 degrees k times
  t     %   Duplicate
  P     %   Flip vertically
        % End (implicit)
        % Display stack, bottom to top (implicit)
```

Comment: Ahh, a magic built-in, quite literally :)

Comment: Ah builtins! I guess I didn't specify anything about using that.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 201 bytes

```javascript
_=>(h=S=>S[1]?S.flatMap(e=>h(S.filter(a=>a!=e)).map(a=>[e,...a])):[S])([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).filter(e=>[[0,3],[0,1],[3,1],[6,1],[1,3],[2,3],[0,4],[2,2]].every(l=>e[l[0]]+e[l[0]+=l[1]]+e[l[0]+l[1]]==15))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NbsIwEITveYrtCa/YWoQU@iNt@gS9NEfLqqzUgSCDIXapqopnT00CrXoZe3Z2Pu3GHE2ou3Yfb3f@3fYN929cijVXXFYq18@VbJyJL2YvLJdrkWzrou2E4dLcsEWU25QlpyxJKY1GfFKVRqFymlNBd7SgJd3TAz1qvJYTSqkZFZqS5kmLQZeD5sN8fknvhv9ca2mPtvsSjkurnJppPR3fKbt0568bDHO@QOy3ZtXW1SEAQyMwa3wHwtkI4fBhOgu@gesGwncGUPtdiLCy8dV/pk6IpovA5WVfBtfWVgxTuoRTKDAV/8hnaLoaCoKlHqkj1zsrnV@JkS4Cyo1vd2ICEzwTTtn/NcxO/Q8)

## Explanation

The integers 1 thru 9 should appear once each in the magic square, so the sum of all elements is \$\frac{9(9+1)}{2}=45\$ using a relatively simple formula.

Therefore, since each row forms one-third of the magic square, the sum of each row should equal 15 (and, by definition, the sums of columns and three-length diagonals must also equal 15).

The first thing my code does is that it creates all permutations of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` (362880 of them to be exact) and checks for the ones which follow specifications. This is done using a special procedure I used in the [Parker square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229545/is-it-a-valid-parker-square?rq=1) challenge.

Rows, columns and diagonals are encoded in a format `[b, i]`:

- `b` is the starting index
- `i` is the number of indexes to add

The obtained subarray for such an array `[b, i]` would be (if the original array was `l`) `l[b], l[b+i], l[b+i+i]`. This is done using a slightly golfier method.

We check if, for each array, the corresponding sub-array (obtained via simple indexing methods) has a sum of 15.

As it turns out there are only eight magic squares of order 3. Right after writing my solution (and golfing it), I returned to this question and clicked the `math.se` link to find that someone had come up with a very simple formula. This notwithstanding, I am posting my answer because I think it offers a more creative approach than simple hard-coding. I am open to suggestions for reducing length.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Great answer.

Comment: @BrowncatPrograms I'm not really new to Code Golf as a matter of fact ;) I used to be RecursiveCo but I wanted to restart for some reason so I signed up again.

Comment: I posted a clarification that the challenge is indeed only for the n=3 case. I think with this constraint, very lean code can be written, and that's what I'm looking for! I expect a few dozen bytes should do it in some language.

Comment: @rajb245 Thanks for the information! Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> 18 bytes

```
9Œ!i⁼ṛɗƇ5s€3§;SEƲƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//OcWSIWnigbzhuZvJl8aHNXPigqwzwqc7U0XGssaH/8OHR@KCrGrigb7CtsK2/w)

The Footer simply formats the output into a nice column of grids, remove it to see the list of matrices

-4 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)

### How it works

```
9Œ!i⁼ṛɗƇ5s€3§;SEƲƇ - Main link. Takes no arguments
9                  - Set the left argument to 9
 Œ!                - All permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      ɗ 5          - Group the previous 3 links into a dyad f(p, 5):
   i               -   Index of 5 in p
     ṛ             -   Yield 5
    ⁼              -   Does the index of 5 equal 5?
       Ƈ           - Keep those permutations for which f(p, 5) is true
         s€3       - Split each into a 3x3 matrix
                ƲƇ - Keep those matrices for which the following is true:
            §      -   Sums of the rows
              S    -   Sums of the columns
             ;     -   Concatenate
               E   -   Are all equal?
```

Comment: Out of the squares with all the row and column sums equal those which also have their diagonal sums also equal are those with \$5\$ in the centre. As such you can filter these from the permutations and save four bytes [like this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/y6CTFTIdjEx2OtZsWP2paY3xouXWw67FNx9r/H253BwpkPWrcd2jboW3/AQ). Still doesn't beat hardcoding one and constructing all symmetries though (currently for that I have 16).

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's a nice observation, thanks!

Comment: this approach was what i was expecting when i asked the question; i had not considered basing the algorithm on rotations/reflections of a single hardcoded literal. great answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>89</s> 83 bytes

The 8 magic squares of order 3 are all just rotations / reflections of each other, so this stores one of them and calculates the remaining ones.

```python
exec("x='672','159','834'"+(';*map(print,*x),print();x=[*zip(*x)][::-1]'*4)[:-6]*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7UiNVlDqcJW3czcSF1H3dDUEkhaGJuoK2lrqFtr5SYWaBQUZeaV6GhVaOqAWRqa1hW20VpVmQUaQLHYaCsrXcNYdS0TzWgrXbNYLSPN//8B)

A few bytes can be saved by using an uglier output format: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8JW3czcSF1H3dDUEkhaGJuoc6XlFymUK2TmKVToVERbWekaxlqlVqQma6hrlevYVmUWaGiVQ4Q1rQuKMvNKNMo1rdW1TDT//wcA)

---

Here are two programs with numpy that don't use hardcoding. The first one is quite slow, 157 bytes:

```python
import itertools as I,numpy as N
for p in I.permutations(N.r_[1:10]):d=N.r_[p].reshape(3,3);{*d.sum(0),*d.sum(1),d.trace(),d[:,::-1].trace()}-{15}or print(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc1BCsMgEIXhfU/hUouRSOjG0gNkkwuEUKRaIlQdxskihJzdNqXdff/bPFhpzqmrNUTISCyQR8r5VZgtrJdpibAeHE7PjAxYSKxX4DEuZCnkVPig8D5qo9tJGHf7FkwKfZkteN7JTly3s1NlibwV8ictpFOE9uH5R6ORxjR6@i97s@nLfvxhSMSdqPUN)

And the second one is decently fast, 175 bytes:

```python
from numpy import*
from itertools import*
d=r_[[*permutations(r_[1:10])]].reshape(-1,3,3)
print(d[all(c_[sum(d,1),sum(d,2),trace(d,0,1,2),trace(flip(d,2),0,1,2)]==15,axis=1)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclLCsMgFIXheVaRoQZbYkMnBVciEiQxRPBxuV6hWb0NDbSz/3wHDtpzmlrbMMc@1QhH7yNkpKH7kieHlHMoP14VzloP4DBWsuRzKuwU@ZKj4cbc0ZXdgmM3KSYx8Q7QJ2KrtiGwZdalRrYKycUVDy4I7eLOHIX8zy14uO6LjVLyKezbFyW54a19AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>79</s> <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 70 bytes

*Edit: -6 bytes thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen).*

```r
m=matrix(c(2,7,6,9,5,1,4,3,8),3)
while(print(m<-t(print(m[3:1,])))-2)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCI1nDSMdcx0zHUsdUx1DHRMdYx0JTx1iTqzwjMydVo6AoM69EI9dGtwTGjDa2MtSJ1dTU1DXSNPz/HwA)

Hardcodes one square and loops though its rotations, displaying also a transposition with every iteration.

Abuses the fact that `while` takes only the first element in a vector/matrix to check the looping condition.

Comment: [1 byte less](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCI1nDSMdcx0zHUsdUx1DHRMdYx0JTx1iTqzwjMydVo7o4I79cI1fTuqAoM69EowTI1NQ1qdXMtQUyo42tDHViNf//BwA)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks! That's some archaeological work here ;-)

Comment: yes, it's nice how sometimes good old questions suddenly get dug-up to the top of the main list...  And here's [5 more bytes less](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCI1nDSMdcx0zHUsdUx1DHRMdYx0JTx1iTqzwjMydVo6AoM69EI9dGtwTGjDa2MtSJ1dTU1DXSNPz/HwA), I think...

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>29</s> 21 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Well, this is <s>pretty damned</s> *slightly* less hideous! Outputs a 3D-array.

```
4o!z49#ë7816ì ò3
cUmy
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=NG8hejQ5I%2bs3ODE27CDyMwpjVW15&footer=VvEgrm24t8NxUrI) (footer formats output into squares)

```
4o!z49#ë7816ì ò3\ncUmy
4o                         :Range [0,4)
  !z                       :For each rotate the following that many times
    49#ë7816               :  492357816
            ì              :  To digit array
              ò3           :  Partitions of length 3
                \n         :Assign to variable U
                  c        :Concat
                   Um      :  Map U
                     y     :    Transpose
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>102</s> 91 bytes

```hs
r=reverse
m=map
[id,r,m r,r.m r]<*>m(m$m((+0).read.pure).show)[[276,951,438],[294,753,618]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZLCoMwEADQvadw4SKxQ/D/gdobeIKQRcABQx0Nk7YeP9rN4602vHHbYuSJ8YccMKGJrE/Iuv2fOfXs9k@m3QIMlDKwujXP/EWCMhLiUUjFaBflv4xShfU4pdZV38HYltDUgwFdjQ30bQ1dORgT4wU)

Doesn't actually bother calculating anything, just compresses a hard-coded output.

There are some tactics used for compression

1. We encode each row as a base 10 number and use `m((+0).read.pure).show` to turn it into a list of intergers.
2. We only encode 2 of the squares and use flips to get the remaining squares.

I tried also other methods

- Only encoding the first two rows / columns and calculating the remainder
- Encoding each starting square only as a single number and splitting it into pieces

Plus some specific optimizations that only make sense with the above (e.g. multiply by 33 or 66).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

```
9Lœε3ô}ʒ4.DÅ\ªsÅ/ªsÅ|ªO˜Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufo5HNbjQ9vqT01yUTP5XBrzKFVxYdb9cFkzaFV/qfnHO7@/x8A)

Brute force, takes ~42 seconds to run on TIO.

**Attempted explanation**

```
9Lœε3ô}                      # All possible 3×3 squares (1..9 permutations, chunk in 3 pieces)
       ʒ4.D                  # Filter by (Create 4 copies of the current square first to get the parts)
           Å\ªsÅ/ªsÅ|ª       # Take the rows, cols and diagonals in a list (Through builtins and appending into one another)
                      O˜Ë    # Flattened sums are equal? Determines magic square (filter)
```

Or, 23 bytes if flat lists of magic squares are acceptable:

```
9Lœʒ3ô4.DÅ\ªsÅ/ªsÅ|ªO˜Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufo5FOTjA9vMdFzOdwac2hV8eFWfTBZc2iV/@k5h7v//wcA)

Comment: [**20 bytes**: ``9Lœ3δôʒ`yÅ\yÅ/yø`)OË``](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufoZONzWw5vOTUpofJwawwQ61ce3pGg6X@4@/9/AA): `ε3ô}` can be `3δô`; `Å|` can be `ø` (no idea why `Å|` is even a builtin tbh.. maybe it vectorizes or something; but I personally haven't used it yet); `ʒ4.DÅ\ªsÅ/ªsøªO˜Ë` can be `ʒDÅ\ªyÅ/ªyøªO˜Ë` (`y` is the value of filters/maps/foreach loops, so no need for the duplicates + swaps), after which it can be golfed 1 byte further to ``ʒ`yÅ\yÅ/yø`)OË`` (or alternatively `ʒDø«yÅ\ªyÅ/ªOË`).

Comment: Oh actually, just `ʒDøyÅ\yÅ/)O˜Ë` is enough for the final part, so it's [**19 bytes**](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0ufoZONzWw5vOTXJ5fCOysOtMUCsr@l/es7h7v//AQ).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
l="276","951","438"
exec"r=zip(*l);l=r[::-1];print r,l,;"*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8dWycjcTElHydLUEEiaGFsocaVWpCYrFdlWZRZoaOVoWufYFkVbWekaxloXFGXmlSgU6eToWCtpmfz/DwA)

Prints the eight arrays space-separated.

Comment: Why the last comma? Without it seems to work fine for -1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8dWycjcTElHydLUEEiaGFsocaVWpCYrFdlWZRZoaOVoWufYFkVbWekaxloXFGXmlSgU6eRYK2mZ/P8PAA "Python 2 – Try It Online"). (Is it outgolfing xnor, or was it just a spelling mistake?)

Comment: @pajonk It would make two different separators between outputs (spaces and newlines), and it's not clear to me that's allowed.

Comment: Ah, ok. I get it now. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

```ruby
r=259149258
"

Q\x1EG\x1EQ
".bytes{|x|p (r+=x*1780218).digits 1000}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8jWyNTS0MTSyNSCS4mLKzCmwtDVHUQEcinpJVWWpBZX11TUFChoFGnbVmgZmlsYGBlaaOqlZKZnlhQrGBoYGNT@/w8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•G´dI•S3ô4F=í=ø
```

This hard-coded approach is 4 bytes shorter than [the brute-force generator approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233921/generate-all-3-times-3-magic-squares#comment534860_233936).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMi90NbUjyBdLDx4S0mbraH19oe3vH/PwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
•G´dI•    # Push compressed integer 276951438
      S   # Convert it to a list of digits: [2,7,6,9,5,1,4,3,8]
       3ô # Split it into triplets to a 3x3 matrix: [[2,7,6],[9,5,1],[4,3,8]]
4F        # Loop 4 times:
  =       #  Print the current matrix with trailing newline (without popping the matrix)
   í      #  Reverse each row
    =     #  Print that matrix without popping as well
     ø    #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•G´dI•` is `276951438`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 15 bytes (30 nibbles)

```
:;`.`/3`D10`'.$\$.$\$ 1081f18e
```

```
       `D10                     # get base-10 digits of
                      1081f18e  # data in hex: 1081f18e
                                # (digits are 2,7,6,9,5,1,4,3,8);
    `/3                         # split into chunks of 3
  `.                            # and iterate over this while unique:   
             .$                 #   map over each group of 3 digits
               \$               #     reversing them
           `'                   #   and transpose the result;
 ;                              # now save these 4 magic squares
:                               # and join them to
                 .$             # each of themselves
                   \$           # reversed
```

[image]
Using the decimal number `276951438` directly (instead of encoding it as data in hex) also comes-out at 15 bytes (`` :;`.`/3`p276951438`'.$\$.$\ ``), since the final argument `$` of program code can be omitted & added implicitly by Nibbles.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 317 bytes

```
++++++>++>-[----->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<<<<<<<]++++++++++>->++++>+++>----->++++++>++>-->----->+>>+++++>-----<<<<<<<<<<<<
<[->>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<.>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<.>>>>>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<<<<<..>>>>>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<<<<<.>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<.>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<..<<[->>>+>->>>->>+>>>+>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>]
```

Score includes one unnecessary newline for "clarity."

Line 1 sets the code up.

Line 2 prints a vertically mirrored pair (separated by `.`) on three rows, then the horizontal mirrors of the first pair (Slightly odd but more user readable than some other answers!)

Then, internally, the six values off the `4 5 6` diagonal are adjusted (by +/-6 each) to flip the square diagonally, and line 2 is run again to print the other four squares.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwzsgEg3WhcE7LSxQxskEKsNB3ZADRADgEyIfoSJujAhOzuoYhBANonLJlrXzk4PAm2g0A4EUMVAACKOXQ4sT1ABToPRHAAUBjnLDuQ7OxDWhnBsUALBLvb/fwA)

**Commented code**

```
++++++>++>-                                                                 FIll cells 0 1 and 2 with 6 2 and 255 respectively for looping
[----->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<<<<<<<]                                 Iterate 255/5=51 times to fill cells 3 to 14 with ASCII "2"
++++++++++>                                                                 Cell 2 = 10 for linefeed
->++++>+++>----->++++++>++>-->----->+>>+++++>-----<<<<<<<<<<<<              Adjust cells 3 to 14 to 276/951/438/ (cannot include period in comments so used slash instead)
<[->                                                                        Iterate twice (counter in cell 1)
  >.>.>.>.<.<.<.<.>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<.>>>>>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<<<<<..   Output characters for 1st pair of squares (each row needs more arrows to get away from cell 2 linefeed) 
  >>>>>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<<<<<.>>>>>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<<<<<.>.>.>.>.<.<.<.<..   Output characters for 2nd pair of squares (basically the reverse of the first)
  <<[->>>+>->>>->>+>>>+>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<]>                                      Flip diagonal by ajusting the 6 values off the 4 5 6 diagonal plus or minus 6
]                                                                           And loop to output 3rd and 4th pairs of squares
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
”)‴vv»!C”Ｆ⁴«Ｆ²«Ｄ‖»⟲»⎚
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJwtAsJs/Y1Dwmz8TSSEnTmistv0hBw0RToZqLE8w0AjM5XUpzCzSA0pycQalpOanJJWBOLRdnUH5JYkkqiFfL5ZyTmlgEZP7//1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
”)‴vv»!C”
```

Write a compressed magic square of digits to the canvas.

```
Ｆ⁴«Ｆ²«Ｄ‖»⟲»
```

Output all the rotations and reflections of the canvas.

```
⎚
```

Clear the canvas so that there's no implicit output.

The squares can be padded for easier viewing at a cost of 3 bytes:

```
←＆!↶⸿⦃3εⅉ‽”Ｆ⁴«Ｆ²«Ｄ‖»⟲»⎚
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREMpJk/BwtAMSBqbmgNJE0sjhZg8JU1rrrT8IgUNE02Fai5OMNMIzOR0Kc0t0ABKc3IGpablpCaXgDm1XJxB@SWJJakgXi2Xc05qYhGQ@f//f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

If two columns of four squares is acceptable output, then for 17 bytes:

```
”←＆!↶⸿⦃3εⅉ‽”⟲Ｃ‖Ｃ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREMpJk/BwtAMSBqbmgNJE0sjhZg8JU1rrqD8ksSSVOf8gkoNEC81LSc1uQTMtTq0RtP6////umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
”←＆!↶⸿⦃3εⅉ‽”
```

Output a padded magic square. (An unpadded square would save 3 bytes, but it would make the output format unreadable.)

```
⟲Ｃ
```

Make a 90° rotated copy.

```
‖Ｃ¬
```

Make four reflected copies of each copy. (One of these is reflected both horizontally and vertically, which is equivalent to a 180° rotation. Also the horizontal and vertical reflections are simply 180° rotations of each other. This therefore produces all of the rotations and their reflections.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 70 bytes

```perl
map{say for/.../g,''}map$_*1780218+275171220,unpack"W*",'\zÁßİĺ'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saC6OLFSIS2/SF9PT08/XUddvRYoqBKvZWhuYWBkaKFtZG5qaG5oZGSgU5pXkJicrRSupaSjzsgdU3W48fD8IxuO7FL///9ffkFJZn5e8X9d39KSNAsgVWaqZ2gAAA)

Borrowed method from @dingledooper's python3 answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 47 bytes

```apl
⎕←(3 3⍴⍕)¨1↓+\50863752,1780218×1+⎕UCS'~	PFP	'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtEzSMFYwf9W551DtV89AKw0dtk7VjTA0szIzNTY10DM0tDIwMLQ5PN9QGKg51Dlav4wyQdZMN4FT//x8A)

nice, my sixth APL answer

fast hardcoding (fork of dingledooper method)

`'`...`'` magic string

`⎕UCS` cast to unicode codepoints

`1+` increment

...`×` multiply by magic

...`,` prepend by magic

`+\` cumulative sum

`1↓` decapitate

`(`...`)¨` for each

`⍕` stringify

`3 3⍴` mold to 3×3 matrix

`⎕←` to stdout

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 215 bytes, intractable for n>3

```hs
import Data.List
m n|let g=sum[1..n^2]`div`n=filter(\s->and[all((g==).sum)(m++[d])|
 m<-[s,reverse.transpose$s],let d=map(\i->m!!i!!i)[0..n-1]]).
 map(takeWhile(>[]).map(take n).iterate(drop n))$permutations[1..n^2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xbwIxDIV3fkWQbkgEF5V2bW5i7N4hpMLSuWAR56LYMPHfr@mA5MXf8/N7V5Ab5ryuxHVpao6g4L9IdMOmPDOquQS5czx4X37e03mmx7mEX8qKzZ5knKDMEXK29hKC8/3UWd7t4pzcc2P4c4yyb/jAJui1QZG6CA6S9v@v58BQ7YnGibdb6uPiW88ZDyk5391dVLjh95Uy2il2@EKmOE@9AijauS21726o2PiuoLQUeRVeGaiE2qjowOZj/QM)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 361 bytes, intractable for n>4

```hs
import Data.List
s 0 l=[[]]
s n[]=[]
s n(a:b)=map(a:)(s(n-1)b)++s n b
m n|let g=sum[1..n^2]`div`n=
 filter(\m->g==sum(map(\i->m!!(n-i-1)!!i)[0..n-1]))$
 filter(\m->g==sum(map(\i->m!!i!!i)[0..n-1]))$concatMap permutations$
 filter(all((g==).sum).transpose)$concatMap(sequence.map permutations)$
 filter(([1..n^2]==).sort.concat)$s n$filter((g==).sum)$s n[1..n^2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBTsQgEIbvfQpIeoBsSlrjyYQ9edQnYGt2WnF3IkwRqCffvdI11c1evP2B//sY5gzp3Tq3LOjDFDN7hAzqCVOuEmuZ08b0fYlkem0uQcDDILWHUIIUSVDTyUHuduWKDZVn9OVsZiedZm86pejlrj@@4ueRdMXe0GUbxcE3@5NeG2L1HLDZe86LCYuLc5SmLWDT9VLW/0B4Ux8nGiE/Q2DBRj9nyDhR@rOAc0IUjVRFJFWOQClMyV6RItmP2dJolb/RXE0jtr9dVGVx6oeXddlDvZV@H1pPN2LxgKRDRMq1Z/ect8s3)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 472 bytes, intractable for n>5

```hs
import Data.List
m n=let
 g=sum[1..n^2]`div`n
 t 1 _ s x l=[[x]|sum x==s]
 t i 0 0 r l=map([]:)(t(i-1)n g(l++r)[])
 t i j s (a:b) l|i>0&&j>0&&s>0=map(\(e:f)->(a:e):f)(t i(j-1)(s-a)b l)++t i j s b(l++[a])
 t _ _ _ _ _=[]
 u s[c]=[[s]|elem s c]
 u s(a:b)=[e:f|e<-a,f<-u(s-e)b]
 v m@([c]:_)=[transpose$m]
 v m=[x:y|x<-u g m,y<-v(map(\\x)m)]
 in
 filter(\m->g==sum(map(\i->m!!(n-i-1)!!i)[0..n-1])).
 filter(\m->g==sum(map(\i->m!!i!!i)[0..n-1])).
 concatMap v$t n n g[1..n^2][]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFBasMwEEX3OcUYQpBwZOxCNyYyXXTZnkBRU8VVXKWSYizFOOC7u@OYrLooA0Lov/9nGH2r8KOtnSbj2ksX4VVFlb2ZEFcOPLc6rqDh4epEkWX@40l@fpn@068gQgEHCDCA5UIMckQGBs6DnDUDOVaHmlMtEbKkJBLDCuqhITZNOyokXcAzhhBVHinY0VT5ZnOej1Dld@ue6PJEWYWEpngjaCFnDCKBKXoES9P0kXKck4Vagg@P4gInukIQtcRBgxy11Q7penm@t@YCu4x6x9T2tGNXzNb0iHoP7oWgsTwgEjvlQ3sJeu0WiYuhvI0DGqABt73tWE/uM@8H6igyBvd0Mjbqjuwdqxo@L3JBDKtckhDP5qUkiaEix/2yQlKa/WMyf/D64msV31UL/TqCx2oe3yXk5JTxvO2Mj2sHz0mST78)

Answer (score 0):

## [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html)/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <del>165</del> <del>163</del> <del>155</del> 153 bytes

Using the `magic` function directly in MATLAB/Octave for a \$3\times3\$ magic square would only generate a single solution, not all \$8\$ possible solutions.

\$\textbf{Saved 12 bytes thanks to the comment of @ceilingcat} \$

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsMgFESv4ir9n0qJEUui/MNINa0QG9G017cm2XUxMPNmMbM@Nvv1tSZKPscCQk9oEmiukJSZ18wCCS3vwzj2PMzMLguUT4RM2ZeXTR4SBK6RSy4RiYTquqO/Xc60BxfsEzL@g3Wb@h0fHFlsq5r7t7sKpGyaYU3VhZLg7IZ2Dk39AQ)

```
p=perms(1:9);p(:,5)=5;for i=1:362880,if all(sum(r=reshape(p(i,:),3,3))==15&&sum(r.')==15&sum(diag(r))==15&sum(diag(rot90(r)))==15) m(:,:,end+1)=r;end end
```

---

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9NCsIwEIX3PcWsNIFBGttqf@hJQhehTTVgTExaF718TYoILnSYgWG@x2Oe6SfxlOtqoQUrnfaEMzhCBjmc4AwlVB1tEh3oIp3xJEMInYbbaByoltVeLZJYZDSBUC4ouSUKWZ1TLDCuRV3SrvlgJ/1VWEkc8gyzaB@JGkF5@ZjFjfhZE0eRswK27ijsdt/0sP/LByUuwYIiK34wM1VpVGyS7YFYMWcvppBSo3s/Ju9DEmdQ3hIdjuv6Ag)

```
p = perms([1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9]);
m = zeros(3, 3, 0);
for i=1:size(p,1)
    r = [p(i,1:4),5,p(i,5:8)];
    r = reshape(r,[3,3]);
    if isequal(sum(r),[15 15 15]) && isequal(sum(r.'),[15 15 15]) && isequal(sum(diag(r)),15) && isequal(sum(diag(rot90(r))),15)
        m = cat(3,m,r);
    end
end
disp(m);
```